# Paypal sandbox doesn't work?

Tags: paypal-sandbox

After clicking paypal button it sends me to a page to login so I can pay the item. However, sandbox won't let me in. It says username or password is incorrect or something like that. But when I switch to a real paypal, I can get in. I don't know what I am missing here. Help pls...

Comment: create sand box test account To Create test account follow this link [enter link description here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sandbox-getting-started-guide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May sound dumb but do you have sandbox account?

Comment: yah, I have set a premier and a buyer account. Each one configured manually.

Comment: Another dumb question, have you set a different URL for sandbox?
Also, what language are you programming this part?
Can you show us the code? No need to display the id/pass obviously.

Answer (score 3):

You log in to PayPal sandbox using an email like `john.smith@gmail.com`. Then you create sellers and buyers, Paypal generates fake emails like `john.sm343443.per@gmail.com` with a password.
That's the one you have to use for checkout, not `john.smith@gmail.com`.